# How can you do message interception in MassTransit?

Tags: c#, masstransit

I want to inspect each message before it hits consumers or sagas.
I think I want an IInboundMessageInterceptor but I can't see an easy way to inject a custom one.
How can I achieve message interception in MT? And/Or how can I configure the bus with a custom IInboundMessageInterceptor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following.
Your interceptor must implement IInboundMessageInterceptor

```
  Bus.Initialize(sbc =>
            {
                // ... Initialise Settings ...

                var busConfiguratorr = new PostCreateBusBuilderConfigurator(bus =>
                    {

                        var interceptorConfigurator = new InboundMessageInterceptorConfigurator(bus.InboundPipeline);
                        interceptorConfigurator.Create(new MyIncomingInterceptor(bus));
                    });

                sbc.AddBusConfigurator(busConfiguratorr);
            });
```

You can then write an interceptor like so

```
    internal class MyInboundInterceptor : IInboundMessageInterceptor
{
    public MyInboundInterceptor(ServiceBus bus)
    {

    }

    public void PreDispatch(IConsumeContext context)
    {
        IConsumeContext<AwesomeCommand> typedContext;
        if (context.TryGetContext(out typedContext))
        {
            // Do SOmething with typedContext.Message
        }
    }

    public void PostDispatch(IConsumeContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Adam, 
I have more than one message to Intercept, so shall i have to define multiple IConsumeContext like given below:
IConsumeContext<AwesomeCommand1> typedContext;
IConsumeContext<AwesomeCommand2> typedContext;
IConsumeContext<AwesomeCommand3> typedContext;

Please help me on this..